# How to install MITIE NLP on Windows for RASA NLU?

Tags: python, nlp, anaconda, chatbot, rasa-nlu

I am trying to install the MITIE as described in the [RASA documentation](http://rasa-nlu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#first-alternative-mitie).

Where they are trying to clone and install the repository [NLP Mitie](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE) using the Python command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE.git
```

I am getting this screen:
[image: Some permission error]

I have also downloaded the NLP Mitie and builded the tools using CMake on Windows successfully.

But I am confused as how to integrate it with RASA NLU.

In the RASA documentation they are including a total_word_feature_extractor.dat in the "mitie_file" key in the config file.

Any Pointers would be helpful as to how to install MITIE and integrate it with RASA.

Comment: I know I see a decent amount of Windows related requests on the Rasa Github. Some of these ML tools are just harder to get running on Windows. I can't help you specifically get it running on Windows as I don't have a good Windows machine to test it on. But perhaps you could run it in Docker so that you don't have to worry about the specific MITIE setup.

Comment: @CalebKeller Any pointers as how to integrate it with RASA after installing MITIE through Docker?

Comment: Sorry I was meaning running Rasa with MITIE already connected: `docker run rasa/rasa_nlu:latest-mitie`

Comment: @CalebKeller can you tell how to do it with docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For UNIX O.S:**

`pip install git+https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE.git`

---

**For Windows O.S:**

I solved my issue by doing the following, hope it helps someone in the future.

1) Firstly clone the git package from [MITIE's official GIT page](https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE).

2) After downloading, Seems like `~\MITIE-master\mitielib` has a `__init__.py` file which makes the directory a valid Python module.
Navigate to the `~\MITIE-master\mitielib` folder, it will look something like this:

[image: contents of mitielib directory]

3) Packages installed from pip reside in the `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\` directory. Make a new folder called mitie and paste the contents there.

[image: After copying into site-packages folder]

4) Lastly modify your configuration file as follows, in the mitie_file key's value provide the path to the total_word_feature_extractor.dat file:

```
{
    "project": "xyz",
    "path": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\RASA\\models",
    "response_log": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\RASA\\logs",
    "pipeline": ["nlp_mitie", "tokenizer_mitie", "ner_mitie", "ner_synonyms", "intent_entity_featurizer_regex", "intent_classifier_mitie"], 
    "data": "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\RASA\\data\\examples\\RASAFormat.json",
    "cors_origins": ["*"],
    "mitie_file" : "C:\\Users\\xyz\\Desktop\\total_word_feature_extractor.dat",
    "aws_endpoint_url": null,
    "token": null,
    "num_threads": 2,
    "port": 5000
}
```

Comment: What configuration file are you referring in the step#4?

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee.. can you elaborate step#4 ? where and how to implement this

Comment: @MSG the RASA config file